# Can I use db.collection with a variable as the collection name?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to make my mongodb database with a collection for each user, and each collection will be named the same as the username.

Let's say I get the username with a function and save it on a variable named x; can I use:

```
var x = getUserName(name);
    db.createCollection(x, options);

db.x.find();
db.x.insert();
```

And so on?

Will it work? or will it look for a collection named "x" and not the the value of the variable x?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [db.getCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/) for this:

```
var x = getUserName(name);
db.createCollection(x, options);

db.getCollection(x).find();
db.getCollection(x).insert();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative syntax is to use square brackets, like this:

```js
var x = getUserName(name);
db.createCollection(x, options);

db[x].find();
db[x].insert();
```